# Controversial book by two data scientists, anybody knows the name?

Tags: android

My question is more about a book rather than ebook, so it probably would fall outside the domain of ebooks but as there is no literature or books.stackexchange.com hence using this. I am sure this will be outside the domain. The book whose name escapes me is written by two data scientists who took public stats of names of people born in 70's and 80's and from that data made a book having some interesting conclusions :-

a. If you have Africanized names you will not get a job or get a low-income job, if you have an White American name you will suceed in life a bit more.

b. Local Crime didn't become severe in States because women had rights and could choose to legally abort (even though that is only possible in some States or something.)

Those conclusions drew flak from the Republican party and there were some counters given, does anybody know the name of that book.

I am using a tag as a tag is necessary although it's not about android or something else.

Does anybody know the book.If you feel like voting down the question because of the non-technical nature of the question, please do but also answer the question.

Comment: This is obviously and completely off-topic for this site. I appreciate that there may be no SE community for which it is on-topic, but that is not a reason to post it here.

Comment: These types of questions are exactly what the chat site is for (and we need more people to participate). The appendix: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12058/the-appendix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freakanomics. Steven Levitt and Stephen J. Dubner

Comment: Thank you Hugh, it was there but not there :)